# FCM Schedule delivery date or time of push notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have working with FCM console to send push notification and it has an option to schedule the delivery date.

But in the references, this API is not documented as an option. I need to know if its possible to push a notification with predefined delivery date through a POST request.

Comment: Hi @Herbey. did you find any solution to schedule push notification using API's.

Answer (score 25):

If you're looking for a public API of FCM for a scheduled push or a payload parameter where you can set the push date, unfortunately, there's nothing like it as of the moment.

You must implement your own App Server and implement the scheduled push yourself (also mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39524734/4625829)).

Comment: Any update on this since last year?  Has anyone found a way to set the "Delivery date" for a notification when not creating the notification via the FCM Console?

Comment: @Rbar There is no update at the moment. Will update my answer as soon as there is.

Comment: Hi @AL. did you find any solution to schedule push notification using API's.

Comment: @YBDevi Unfortunately, FCM still doesn't have that feature when using the API.

Comment: Thanks @AL.Hope FCM add this feature it will help a lot.

Comment: Hi @AL. any improvement on this so far?

Comment: @choopage None as of the moment. Unfortunately.

Comment: You can schedule using Firebase Console, so i believe soon we'll have it on API's

Comment: Any updates? Looking to put a 24 hour delay on notifications for free users.

Comment: Hi guys, feel free to file a feature request here.. It appears we still don't have any updates on it yet. firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: For anyone looking, this feature is now implemented in the FCM Compose interface - you can choose `Recipient Timezone` in the `Schedule` section.

Comment: Hey @Adam, the scheduling *in the console* has been there for a while. The question was focusing on an option that can be used with *the FCM APIs*. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to ALs excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641151/209103): you could:

- send a data message with FCM straight away,
- in that message include a field with when the message is to be displayed,
- them in your application code show the message when it is due.

This has the added advantage that the message can be delivered when the user has a connection, and then displayed when they don't have a network connection.

Of course this only works if you can determine the exact message before it is displayed. If the contents of the message can only be known right before it is displayed, you will need to implement your own mechanism to schedule deliver as AL said in his answer.