# Migrate push notifications to FCM or Amazon SNS?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm using legacy binary APNs and GCM and now I want to upgrade to their newer versions of these services, as recommended on their websites. All I need are push notifications to both iOS and Android devices, though I'd like to add *"scheduled notifications"* or *"bulk push notifications"* feature as explained in [Firebase Notifications docs](https://firebase.google.com/features/notifications/).

I'm curious what are the reasons why would someone with these requirements choose Amazon SNS over FCM? Are there any downsides choosing FCM? Is this just a personal preference, meaning the both services will work great for these requirements? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned *scheduled notifications* can only be done when sending the message via the Firebase Console. If you intend to have implement your own App Server and send the message using the FCM API, you would have to implement the *scheduled* push yourself. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641151/4625829))

For the *bulk push notifications*, this one can easily be implemented if you use FCM Topic Messaging.

To answer your post (which is pretty much opinion based), I haven't actually used Amazon SNS before, but going with FCM not only allows you to use the new features (compared to GCM), but it can also be a starting point for you to use the other services (Realtime Database, Analytics, Authentication, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to give Firebase a try, and like you said this question is more opinion based.