# Get Firebase scheduled notifications from app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Looking for a way to get scheduled notifications in Firebase.

From Firebase Dashboard, we can create\see list of scheduled notification, but how to get this list for Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve the list of scheduled notifications visible on your Firebase Console. It can only be viewed, edited, or deleted from the Firebase Console itself.

Scheduled notifications itself can only be made through the Firebase console (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641151/4625829)).