# Scheduling notification Firebase

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, onesignal

I'm using the OneSignal to send notifications. But I need to send the notification according to a date I have in a Firebase document.

Is there a cron job or scheduled for Cordova/Ionic or should I do it differently?

Comment: Are you looking to [schedule delivery of a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640469/fcm-schedule-delivery-date-or-time-of-push-notification)?

Comment: You say you're using OneSignal, so why not just use the [`send_after`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-delivery) parameter?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. At first I was looking for something scheduler. But at the moment send_after will work