# There is way to send all full options appear in firebase cloud messaging create messaging page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the project in asp.net MVC 5 I need to add all option to my client-side app
which is send a push notification to android and ios app
for this scenario, I had created a page like a firebase cloud messaging => 
create message

[image: firebase original page screenshot]

c# code

```
    private static string SendPushNotification()
{
            string response;

            try
            {
            string serverKey = "##########"; 
            string senderId = "#############";
            string deviceId = "//topics/all";

            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Greetings",
                    title = "Augsburg",
                    sound = "Enabled"
                }
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            response = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = ex.Message;
        }

        return response;
}
```

So My query is that

> 1: I could send all these options to my HTTP request or not
>
> 2: There is open to send later open I need to also configure this
>   option
>
> 3: And Target User option?

Could I do this using HTTP request by providing parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not all.For most of the text fields, you can (see the docs for the [HTTP ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)):

   - Message Text = `body`
   - Message label: Nope. See the help text (?), it's just a label that the Firebase Console uses.
   - Delivery Date: See #2.
   - User Segment: See #3.
   - Message title = `title`
   - Android Notification Channel Name = `android_channel_id`
2. [Scheduled notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39640469/4625829) are currently not available for the REST API.
3. [User Segments currently not available yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327164/4625829).

Comment: With all that said, please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post in the future. Cheers!