# FCM send message to topic with local time zone

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for IOS and Android.
I want to send message to topic in certain time 
considering local time zone. 
Is it real by using API?
I know that it's real by using custom scheduler and storing user time zone, but I'm looking for easy way.

Comment: You *can* schedule messages in the [notifications composer panel in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/compose), and you can select for them to be delivered in the user's timezone there. But there is no option in the Firebase Cloud Messaging API to schedule the delivery of messages. Messages sent through the API are delivered as soon as possible after you send them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640469/fcm-schedule-delivery-date-or-time-of-push-notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* schedule messages in the [notifications composer panel in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/compose), and you can select for them to be delivered in the user's timezone there.

[image: Firebase Cloud Messaging notification composer]

But there is no option in the Firebase Cloud Messaging API to schedule the delivery of messages. Messages sent through the API are delivered as soon as possible after you send them. See [FCM Schedule delivery date or time of push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640469/fcm-schedule-delivery-date-or-time-of-push-notification).

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of this.