# Timed Notification of Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have finished the test of Firebase Cloud Messaging, and it's working properly. How can we use Firebase to send timed notifications, just like the local alarm clock?

Comment: add more details about the question, and add the part of code which you tried.

Comment: Scheduling notifications is currently only possible in the Firebase console. The FCM API doesn't have an option to schedule message the delivery. If you need to schedule delivery through the API, you will have to build your own scheduling mechanism on your app server. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640469/fcm-schedule-delivery-date-or-time-of-push-notification