# Flutter Firebase Messaging: How to send push notifications to users at specified time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I have an app that has a Firestore collection with To Do items at a specific time e.g `5:00pm - Go for a walk`

I have created a function that once a user has specified a time, my `cloud functions` can create a push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

However, I want to be able to send the user that push notification at that specific time & date.

Here is my `cloud functions` file

```js
async function onCreateNotification(uid, time, text) {
    const user = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).get();
    // Make this function execute at a specific time
    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
        user.tokens,
        {
            data: {
                user: JSON.stringify(user),
                text: JSON.stringify(text)
            }
        },
        {
            // Required for background/quit data-only messages on iOS
            contentAvailable: true,
            // Required for background/quit data-only messages on Android
            priority: "high"
        }
    ).then((response) => {
        // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
        // the contents of response.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Frank's answer above, I was able to successfully utilize Cloud Tasks and Firebase Cloud Messaging to implement my feature! It's got a few kinks left to work out still, but I figured someone could use this later on if need be.

I mostly based my code from the [suggested article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)

Here's the resulting code
`cloud functions`

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
admin.initializeApp()

exports.createTask = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    log("Create Task")
    const taskClient = new CloudTasksClient();
    let { time, uid, id } = data

    // Get Date from time in format mm-dd-yyyy
    let entryDate = new Date(time[0], time[1], time[2], time[3], time[4],);
    const date = join(entryDate, '-');
    let prevEntry = await admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${uid}/${date}/${id}`).get()
    let prevEntryData = await prevEntry.data()

    if (prevEntryData.hasOwnProperty('expirationTask')) {
        // Delete old expiration task
        await taskClient.deleteTask({ name: prevEntryData.expirationTask })
    }
    // This works now! Now I should create a task on google tasks
    const todayDate = new Date()

    const expirationAtSeconds = (entryDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000 

    const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId
    const location = 'us-central1'
    const queue = 'firestore-ttl'
    const queuePath = taskClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)
    const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/firestoreTtlCallback`
    const docPath = `/users/${uid}/${date}/${id}`
    const payload = {
        docPath,
        uid,
    }
    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        },
        scheduleTime: {
            seconds: expirationAtSeconds
        }
    }
    const [response] = await taskClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })
    const expirationTask = response.name;
    const update = { expirationTask }
    // update the entry with the expiration task name
    await admin.firestore().doc(docPath).update(update)
    log("Done with Create Task")
    return ['Success!']
})

// Callback to send message to users
exports.firestoreTtlCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const payload = req.body;
        let entry = await (await admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).get()).data();
        let tokens = await (await admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${payload.uid}`).get()).get('tokens')
        // log(entry);
        // log(tokens)
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
            tokens,
            {
                data: {
                    title: JSON.stringify('App'),
                    body: JSON.stringify(entry['text'])
                }
            },
            {
                contentAvailable: true,
                priority: 'high'
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            log('Successfully sent message:')
            log(response)
            admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).update({ expirationTask: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete() })
        }).catch((error) => {
            log('Error in sending Message')
            log(error)
        })
        res.status(200)
    } catch (err) {
        log(err)
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging API delivers the messages as soon as possible after you call it. It doesn't have a way to schedule delivery for the future. So you will have to implement that yourself.

Some options:

- You can use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that periodically checks if there are any messages that need to be delivered.
- You can use Cloud Tasks to dynamically schedule the delivery, instead of periodically checking.

For both of those, also see my answer here: [Is there any TTL (Time To Live ) for Documents in Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173560/is-there-any-ttl-time-to-live-for-documents-in-firebase-firestore)

As another alternative:

- If the message itself is not dynamic, you can [send a data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) to the device right away, and then only display it on the device once the notification is due.

Also see:

- [FCM Schedule delivery date or time of push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640469/fcm-schedule-delivery-date-or-time-of-push-notification)
- [How can scheduled Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications be made outside of the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713668/how-can-scheduled-firebase-cloud-messaging-notifications-be-made-outside-of-the/60714000#60714000)
- [How to Send and receive Scheduled notifications FCM Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900703/how-to-send-and-receive-scheduled-notifications-fcm-flutter)
- And many more of these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+schedule).

Comment: Do you think the combination of these 2 methods would be viable? I am thinking of potentially doing a scheduled Cloud function that will check every day for timed entries and then using creating a google task for each timed entry of that day. I am trying to minimize the load place on the platform

Comment: That could work, but it it's only about ensuring the top-level operation doesn't take too long, you can also do that by running it more regularly, or by triggering the individual sends through a PubSub topic (that's by far the most common way to spread out a Functions workload).