# How can I schedule a cloud message in firebase from a Rails POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This my sample ruby POST request to FCM and I need to schedule the push notification delivery time

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

result = HTTParty.post('http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    :body => { "to" => "< Sample FCM token>",
      "priority" => "high",
      "notification" => {
        "title" => 'Hello World',
        "body" => "Test Message !"
      }}.to_json,

    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'key=<FCM Key>' } )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a public API of FCM for a scheduled push or a payload parameter where you can set the push date, unfortunately, there's nothing like it as of the moment.

You must implement it in your own App Server and implement the schedule push yourself (also mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39524734/4625829)).